# Salting a password with spring 3 security

Tags: java, spring, security, hash, spring-security

I was trying the whole day to find out or google, how to add `salt` to my hashed password during authentication via `Spring 3 security` and make it all to work together. Without salt it works just fine.

```xml
    <!-- authentication from database -->
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:password-encoder hash='md5'/> 
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref='dataSource'

                users-by-username-query="
              select username,password, salt
              from users where username=?"

                authorities-by-username-query="
              select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
              where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " />

        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

And if I'd like to create salted pasword, it's done just by `user.setPassword(md5(somePassword+someSalt));` Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security uses the following pattern for [password encoding](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/BasePasswordEncoder.java#BasePasswordEncoder.mergePasswordAndSalt%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,boolean%29) with salts:

```
 md5(password+"{"+salt+"}")
```

I would however use sha instead of md5.